# How to transform yyyy-mm-ddthh-mm-ssz to yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, html-input

I have an input in my page to capture a date. I need it in "yyyy-mm-dd" format but it's saving it in "yyyy-mm-ddthh-mm-ssz".

```
<input id="celular" type="date" date="yyyy/mm/dd" class="browser-default" ng-model="cumpleanos" >
```

I need to format to yyyy-mm-dd in the front or in the back.

When I inspect the header of the data send I see this:

```
cumpleanos: "2018-03-01T05:00:00.000Z"
```

and the database sends me this error:

> Incorrect date value: '2018-03-01T05:00:00.000Z' for column 'cumpleanos' at row 1

The column `cumpleanos` is a date type column.

Comment: You've almost tagged every language, how about you let us know which language you'd prefer the formatting in, also, this is very trivial, surely you found *something*?

Comment: Just take `substr($in,0,10)`? Better still, use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to ensure it is a valid input, then `format` as needed.

Answer (score -2):

You could just use substring:

```js
var time = "2018-03-01T05:00:00.000Z";
time = time.substring(0,10);

console.log(time);
// "2018-03-01"
```